# Parsing out data from a string using regEx?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading through a bunch of random "Header" information in node.

It looks something like this:

> _Aa:GA1.1.78037747.867108, 44907=5xyz; Webstorm-a36041d5=9fbb-48e9-b19e-e3f0a3282151;
>   srce=coolernode; nsid=1234; **cookie_data**=T%3D1; _gat_PP=1;

**Problem:**
I'm trying to write a regEx or something to parse out "**cookie_data**" value from the string.

Is it possible to convert it to a map or extract **cookie_data**=T%3D1?

I've tried doing:

```
const i= str.indexOf('cookie_data');
const res = str.chatAt(i);
```

But still going nowhere, since I can't keep traversing until i get ';'

Wondering to see if there's any other effective way to extract info?

Comment: You want `T%3D1`?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) package to parse the cookie and you will get all the other values too, not only `cookie_data`

```
const cookie = require('cookie');

const string = '_Aa:GA1.1.78037747.867108, 44907=5xyz; Webstorm-a36041d5=9fbb-48e9-b19e-e3f0a3282151; srce=coolernode; nsid=1234; cookie_data=T%3D1; _gat_PP=1$

const parsed = cookie.parse(string);

console.log(parsed.cookie_data); // T=1 (decoded)
/*
   { '_Aa:GA1.1.78037747.867108, 44907': '5xyz',
   'Webstorm-a36041d5': '9fbb-48e9-b19e-e3f0a3282151',
   srce: 'coolernode',
   nsid: '1234',
   cookie_data: 'T=1',
   _gat_PP: '1' }
*/
```

or since you were trying a regex, use `match` with a capture group to get the value of `cookie_data`, and `decodeURIComponent` to decode the value and get `T=1` instead of `T%3D1`

```js
const string = '_Aa:GA1.1.78037747.867108, 44907=5xyz; Webstorm-a36041d5=9fbb-48e9-b19e-e3f0a3282151; srce=coolernode; nsid=1234; cookie_data=T%3D1; _gat_PP=1;'
const [,data] = string.match(/cookie_data=(.+?);/);
console.log(data, decodeURIComponent(data));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `match` to match the text found between two parts of a string:

```js
const str = '_Aa:GA1.1.78037747.867108, 44907=5xyz; Webstorm-a36041d5=9fbb-48e9-b19e-e3f0a3282151; srce=coolernode; nsid=1234; cookie_data=T%3D1; _gat_PP=1;'
const found = str.match(/cookie_data=([^;]+);/)[1];
console.log(found);
```

Or you can split by semicolons and make an object representing the string, and access the appropriate property:

```js
const str = '_Aa:GA1.1.78037747.867108, 44907=5xyz; Webstorm-a36041d5=9fbb-48e9-b19e-e3f0a3282151; srce=coolernode; nsid=1234; cookie_data=T%3D1; _gat_PP=1;'
const splits = str.split('; ');
const obj = splits.reduce((obj, substr) => {
  if (!substr.includes('=')) return obj;
  const [key, value] = substr.split('=');
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.cookie_data);
```

Comment: The second approach should be preferred as the OP would end up with a parser that provides a general solution for other cases. However, the `_Aa:GA1.1.78037747.867108, ` part seems to need different parse rules to the rest of the string.